# bash script unable execute after a commented line

Tags: bash, unix

Why am I unable to complete my bash script with this `#`-comment?
My script doesn't execute passed the commented line.
Does it have to do with using `\` backlashes in the preceding line?

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -h $HOST_NM     \
                      -p $PORT    \
                      -U postgres \
                      -v v1=$1    \
                      -v v2=$_load \
#                     -f Test.sql
                      -f Test2.sql
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. `\` joins the current line to the next one, so what bash sees is:

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql ... -v v1=$1 -v v2=$_load # -f Test.sql
                      -f Test2.sql
```

You can move the comment to the last line in this particular case:

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -h $HOST_NM     \
                      -p $PORT    \
                      -U postgres \
                      -v v1=$1    \
                      -v v2=$_load \
                      -f Test2.sql
#                     -f Test.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the first six lines of your script are a single line for the shell. A comment stop the interpretation of the current line until its end so there is no way to have the line resuming after the `#` comment.

Should you want to keep the order of options for some reason, you might use that syntax:

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -h $HOST_NM     \
                      -p $PORT    \
                      -U postgres \
                      -v v1=$1    \
                      -v v2=$_load \
                      $(: -f Test.sql) \
                      -f Test2.sql
```

The `$( ... )` is replacing a portion of a command by the execution of what is inside the parenthesis. The `:` is kind of a null command, somewhat similar to a `#` but unlike it, it doesn't end the current line so the outer command line can resume after it.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate more on `$(: -f Test.sql) \` ?  What is the `$` doing?

Comment: Nice idea. `$(...)` evaluates the contents of `()` & result is substituted at that place. `$(: ...)` means, print result of the `:` command, which is always empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Store the options in an array instead. It's easier to comment out arbitrary elements of an array than to deal with line continuations the way you currently are.

```
psql_options=(
     -h "$HOST_NM"
     -p $PORT
     -U postgres
     -v v1="$1"
     -v v2="$_load"
     # -f Test.sql
     -f Test2.sql
)

"$PSQL_HOME"/psql "${psql_options[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A backslash, in this case, escapes a newline. When \ is the last character, the shell keeps reading from the next line to complete reading of the command.

```
/home/atul/myBash> cat -vte tst.sh 
echo one\$
two\$
#three\$
four$
/home/atul/myBash> chmod +x tst.sh
/home/atul/myBash> ./tst.sh
onetwo#threefour
/home/atul/myBash>
```

As per *man bash* 
COMMENTS
... a word **beginning with # causes** that word and
       all remaining characters on that line to be  ignored.

Slighting modifying the tst.sh file

```
/home/atul/myBash> cat -vte tst.sh
echo one\$
two \$
# three\$
four$
/home/atul/myBash> ./tst.sh
onetwo
./tst.sh: line 4: four: command not found
/home/atul/myBash>
```

Note the space after **two** - it makes the **# start a word**. The line is interpreted as a comment. The word **four** is taken as start of another command.